# Bigger fractions without using \dfrac

Tags: math-mode, fractions

Is there any way to make fractions bigger? I know one can use `\dfrac` but is there any code I can use in the document preamble to make *all* fractions bigger?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea; in-line fractions are best typeset in slashed form rather than "two storey".

Answer (score 7):

```
\let\oldfrac\frac
\let\frac\dfrac
```

will make `\frac` be defined to be the same as `\dfrac` and makes `\oldfrac` available if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you like this; normal fractions are presented in `displaystyle` size. This will mean that lines crowd together, so you'll need to fix the spacing of the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\linespread{2}%controls the spacing between lines. Bigger fractions means crowded lines
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 Here is my text with normal fractions
$\frac{3}{4}$ this will cause lines to look crowd together unless you space them differently $\frac{1}{2}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am informed that `\everymath` should basically not be used in LaTeX, since so many of its macros secretly use math mode internally to do things that don't really have to do with math but are somehow easier that way.  This may cause interesting problems.